# CSS - 1140px Grid - IE 7,8 issues - Media Queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

So, I'm using the [1140px css grid](http://cssgrid.net/). It's a responsive css grid design and I'm very impressed with it. However (when will it end??), IE (7, 8) screws up. The author uses css 3 media queries to set styles below 768px. He also uses [this](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) to enable media queries in unsupported browsers. But the styles are never applied in IE (ie 9 works fine though).

I've settled for a rather ugly hack to solve the issue (read - ie specific js file to create style elements when screen size is below 768px). Is there another way round?

Comment: Respond.js is your only solution like the other poster answered below, unless you want to use something more wild like the Chrome frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

respond.js(https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) gets media queries working in unsupported browsers. If you use modernizr this did includes response. Apparently no longer:http://modernizr.com/news/modernizr-25/

Comment: thank you, but that still doesnt solve the issue. I can't crack it.

Comment: you could use conditional comments to load special ie css as the mediaqueries are only really needed for small displays

Answer (score 1):

If you're running it as a file on your PC the js file won't do anything.  Once you put it on a server though, the js will kick in.

Comment: Normal js is only parsed by the browser, not the server. So it doesn't matter if he's developing with a server or just loading the html page into his browser.